# How do you use the verb dub properly?

Tags: verbs

Do you have to say "x dubbed over the actor's voice" or can you just say "dubbed over the actor"? I am wondering if we need to say actor's voice or use actor's instead of actor to imply it's the actor's voice we're referring to.

Here's an example:

> An interpreter dubbed over the president of the United States as he was
>   giving his speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way is fine.  Obviously in a *dubbed* movie it's the voices that have been *dubbed over*, but you can just say you *dubbed over* the actors.

However it's not usually the person speaking who is doing the *dubbing*.  That's done by a sound engineer or someone with a similar job.  In your example it's more common to use the passive voice:

> An interpreter **was dubbed** over the President of the United States as he was giving his speech.